# batch file log multiple telnet sessions

Tags: file, batch-file, logging, telnet

I have a batch file that logs into a device gathers inf and logs out. the data is recorded to a txt file. it then opens another telnet session gathers data and logs. my proble is i have two logs. any way to combine them into one?

```
@echo off
cls
:start
@ECHO OFF
:: Get Info

set /p input1="Enter First IP Address and press ENTER  "
set /p input2="Enter Second IP Address and press ENTER  "

@ECHO OFF
::Run script to Get Info
start telnet.exe -f C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\TELNET\CHANGE_ME_"%input1%".txt "%input1%"
cscript /nologo 1.vbs

timeout /t 3

taskkill /im telnet.exe /f

timeout /t 2

@ECHO OFF
::Run script to Get Info
start telnet.exe -f C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\TELNET\CHANGE_ME_"%input2%".txt "%input2%"
cscript /nologo 1.vbs

echo "DONE!"
pause
```

Comment: `copy file1.txt+file2.txt combined.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate both logs in the end with `type` command

```
type C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\TELNET\CHANGE_ME_"%input1%".txt C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\TELNET\CHANGE_ME_"%input2%".txt > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\TELNET\CHANGE_ME_TOTAL.txt
```

Before that, you'll need to wait until second telnet is finished and maybe kill it like you did with the first one, or second log file will be locked and unreadable.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfect Jean ! Thanks so much!!